# Online nonlinear system's matrix estimation usung matlab simulink

Tags: matlab

There is a nonlinear system which name is 'lect7'([lect7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNejA.png).
I Use Matlab commands `trim` and `linmod` to find the operating point (OP) and linearize the system model at that OP ([My sys)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiClz.png)
I'm interested to know is there any way to get system matrix (A,B,C,D) online and at any cycle in matlab simulink?(I mean in my nonlinear system the Gain (0.707) can changes with time so matrix (A,B,C,D) which obtain using this way doesn't have accuracy when times goes.Is there any way to get these matrix at any time and get the accuracy error between nonlinear model and approximated linear system in simulink online and at every cycle?)